# select from logical list. Common Lisp

Tags: lisp

How to achieve this in Common lisp?

```
(logselect (t nil t) (list1 list2 list3)) ---> (list1 list2)
```

I have coded the below function but I think there is a better way (maybe a built-in function?).

```
(defun logselect (loglist lista)
    (let ((listaL) (maskL) (toremove))
        (setq listaL (mapcar #'list lista)) 
        (setq maskL (mapcar #'cons loglist listaL))
        (setq toremove (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (car (and (car x) (cdr x)))) maskL))
        (remove nil toremove)
    )
)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I mean (logselect (t nil t) (list1 list2 list3)) ---> (list1 list3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done using `LOOP`:

```
(defun logselect (loglist lista)
    (loop for test in loglist
          for value in lista
     when test collect value))
```

If you prefer a more "lispy" solution, you can do it with `mapcan`:

```
(defun logselect (loglist lista)
    (mapcan #'(lambda (test value)
                (when test (list value)))
            loglist lista))
```

`mapcan` is a useful function when you want to use a mapping function to add list elements conditionally. The function returns a list, and they're all concatenated to create the final result, so it can return an empty list if it doesn't want to add something.